# PHP cant read txt file

Tags: php

I have a script that work perfectly with input file except .txt file.
I really dunno whats wrong with it. But if i open other extension (like .csv, .rar, .zip, etc) it works and i got something on my $_POST. 
But if i go with any *.txt file i just get array null on my $_POST.

If i use this code :

```
$sListText = file_get_contents("act20170713.txt");
echo "<br/>".nl2br($sListText);
```

Its just work perfectly. But if i use :

```
$fileexcel = $_FILES['txt']['tmp_name'];
echo $fileexcel;
```

i got an array null only with *.txt file

Can someone explain it to me or maybe have the solution for it?
Any answer will be appreciated. Thank in advance.

Kind regards,
Fondra

I add some screenshot for more detail
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59QH1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw61a.png)

Full code :

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form2" id="form2"> 
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <input id="file" type="file" name="txt" style="text-align:right;-moz-opacity:0;filter:alpha(opacity:0);opacity:1;z-index: 2;"/>     
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3" style="padding-left:4.5%"><input type="submit" name="list" class="btn btn-info" value="Show"/></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3" ><input type="submit" name="clear" class="btn btn-default" value="Clear" style="float:right"/></div>
          </div>
                    </form>
<?php if (isset($_POST['list'])){
        var_dump($_FILES);
        $fileexcel = $_FILES['txt']['tmp_name'];
        echo $fileexcel;
        print_r($_FILES['txt']);

        //echo "test";
        //$sListText = file_get_contents("act20170713.txt");
        //$data = explode("\n", $sListText);
?}
```

Comment: `print_r($_FILES)` to find out - else provide a HTTP request dump and the submit form.

Comment: i gave Array null. if the file is .txt file. thats the only problem.
if the file are not .txt file, it just works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the txt file very larger? Perhaps PHP is choking on the file size? Check `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` php config settings - I've seen situations where the file exceeds `post_max_size` did not return any errors, similar to your situation.

Comment: Yep. Thats the problem. It has 9.988.894 length and 44.534 lines.
Thanks. Because u, i found the only problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can `var_dump($_FILEs)` to see,and check you html form is have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: sorry but nope.
Its like the input file blocking any input from *.txt file (literally).
even i use var_dump i just got array null.
But it works perfectly with other extension (.csv, etc)

Answer (score 0):

This is for PHP 5 on how to read a text file that i found on W3Schools.

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("webdictionary.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("webdictionary.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp)

Hope that helps.

Comment: i can read the ".txt" file manually but i want to read it dynamically.
so thats why i try to use "input file".
but it doesnt work on txt file but well work on csv or other file